# Telerik MVC grid does not work for individual column settings

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I just want to apply settings to an **individual** column and not all the columns in the grid. I tried the following in the grid, but doesn't work. It defaults to **no filter** and **no sortable columns**.

If i have the **Filterable** and **Sortable** properties set on the whole grid, it works fine (for every column though). Again, i just want to apply it for **individual** columns.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Email).Width(200).Filterable(true).Sortable(true); // this does not work
```

How` can this be accomplished? I'm using version 2011.2.712.340 of the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "fooled around" with it noting that I need to set filterable and sortable for the **entire** grid and then individually turn those options on or off for each column